# FTP upload slows down when devices are connected via hub

Tags: networking, tcp

I have a setup with a network hub and three Ethernet devices. One of them is a PC (running windows XP), two others are hardware components that need to communicate with each other over the network. Additionally, both of these components can be accessed via SSH and FTP and run custom version of Linux (LFS).

I'm using a hub (Netgear DS 524) since it allows me to view communication between the devices on the PC comfortably.

This setup works like a charm, with one exception. If I connect the PC directly to the device and try to upload a file via FTP, it works perfectly (the same with SFTP). Download also works. Wiresharks shows absolutely no connection problems.

However, when I connect the PC and one of the devices via hub (the other device powered off and plugged out of hub), I start to have problems with file uploads (with both FTP and SFTP). Every single packet sent to the device gets retransmitted and Collision LED on hub blinks intensively. Download works without problems.

I discovered that when I make the device networking subsystem just a bit busy, packet flow gets better. Simple commands like:

`ping 127.0.0.1 -f > /dev/null` or `while true; do ifconfig eth5; done > /dev/null`

Decrease collision rate by a factor of ten, but just for a couple of seconds. I thought that maybe, somehow, the device responds too fast and that causes the problem. I decreased MTU size in the PC to 576 and that helped a bit too, now about every 15th packet gets retransmitted. Here's the screenshot from Wireshark: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFcxm.png

Do you have an idea how I could improve this situation and get working uploads over hub?

Comment: If you want performance, use a switch instead of a hub.

Comment: @JennyD: As I wrote, I need a hub in order to view packets exchanged between devices for debug purposes. I'm ok with even significant performance drop, but now I'm unable to work.

Comment: You need a better switch, with port mirroring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a duplex mismatch. I'd hard-set the interfaces on all the devices to 100Base-TX, half-duplex (a safe baseline configuration for any 100Base-TX hub) and see if it improves. Once you've got it improved you can experiment with changing things back to full-duplex to see what "breaks" it.

(It's unclear to me if that model hub even supports full-duplex. It looks to be fairly old and [NetGear's documentation](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/mds5001.pdf) seems to be fairly poor.)

Comment: I set all devices to HD, but the problem still persists. I have a theory that the device ignores HD settings and there's something wrong with the driver (I see that ethtool reports link speed 1000, mii-tool 10, and hub lights the 100 LED). Additionally, I can't force any speed on the device, I lose the connection after issuing such request via ethtool (100 gets autonegotiated though) and can't ping the device up until power reset. Issuing mii-tool has completely no effect (ifconfig down/up of course issued). Do you have any idea how I can work around these problems?

Comment: How about one of these?  (a) Use a switch w/ a port-mirror to accomplish what you're trying to do, rather than using a hub. (b) Use a dedicated Ethernet tap. (c) Plug the devices into switches that allow you control the port speed/duplex, then connect the switches together via the hub.

Comment: These sound like the only way to get this working. I tested this hub with two PCs and seen no problems, both autonegotiated HD and were working perfectly OK. There must be something wrong with my device.